# How to properly define many to many EF Core 2.2 configuration via ids only?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

A project using Entity Framework Core 2.2 contains a pair of entities with a many-to-many relationship.

The entities are as follows:

```cs
class Feature
{
    int Id { get; set;}
}
```

```cs
class House
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   ICollection<int> FeatureIds { get; set; }
}
```

As EF Core does not support many-to-many relationship natively yet, I have created a join class.

```cs
class HouseFeature
{
    int FeatureId { get; set; }
    int HouseId { get; set; }
}
```

None of the three classes contains a property for the other entity, only its id. The `Feature` entity neither contains a list of `houses`.

The configuration class for `HouseFeature` looks like:

```cs
class HouseFeatureConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<HouseFeature>
{
    void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<HouseFeature> houseFeatureConfiguration)
    {
    }
}
```

How to configure the EF Core relationship?

All examples I found require properties like `Feature Feature { get; set; }` on top of `int FeatureId { get; set; }`. I have no use for these `Feature Feature { get; set; }` so I prefer to not have them in the model. Is it possible to define the relationship including foreign keys while having `id`-fields only? How?

Comment: class `House` with `ICollection<int> FeatureIds` is more like entity *view* (ViewModel, DTO) rather than *entity*. Even if it can somehow be served for read scenarios like in Tom's answer, it will be just a source of many potential problems - trying to use it inside LINQ to Entities query will be either client eval or exception, adding/removing from it will do nothing etc. Don't do that. Create and map normal `House` entity, turn the current class to `HouseDTO` or something like that, and use `Select` to populate it. And map it back to entity when needed (for instance, when applying changes).

Answer (score 0):

Use the ModelBuilder. Here's an example where it is manually configured:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks you can create a mapping without exposing a collection of link class in your model. However, you can make it private. Also, a mapping to the `ICollection<int>` will not work (and even if it would, it would mean a mapping without the collection of link objects).

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
public class House
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private IEnumerable<HouseFeature> HouseFeatures { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> FeatureIds
    {
        get { return HouseFeatures.Select((hf) => hf.FeatureId).ToList(); }
    }
}

class HouseFeatureConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<HouseFeature>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<HouseFeature> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(nameof(HouseFeature.FeatureId), nameof(HouseFeature.HouseId));
        builder
            .HasOne<House>()
            .WithMany("HouseFeatures") // can't use nameof or expression because it's private member of the House
            .HasForeignKey(nameof(HouseFeature.HouseId));
        builder
            .HasOne<Feature>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(nameof(HouseFeature.FeatureId));
    }
}
```